# React navigation different route params on same route

Tags: reactjs, navigation, native, react-navigation

I have a route in my app that can be navigated to from two different locations.

Specifically:

Home screen (StackNavigation) -> target route

Tab navigation -> target route

I have noticed that react navigation re-uses the same target route component (does not re-mount) regardless of which way the target route is navigated too.

Unfortunately, this means that route params are always the same as the first method used to navigate to the target route.

I would like to focus an input search box when the target route is navigated to from the home screen, but not when navigated via tab navigation.

Initially I was using this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const _focusSearchBar = (payload) => {
        if (props.navigation.getParam('shouldFocus') && searchBar && searchBar.current) {
            searchBar.current.focus();
        }
    }
    let focusSub = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', _focusSearchBar);
    _focusSearchBar();
    return () => focusSub.remove();
}, []);
```

How can I achieve this? Also the target route loads data, so it is probably a good thing that it doesn't remount...

In essence I need a way of determining how the route was navigated too, through the home screen or via tab navigation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html#navigate-to-a-route-multiple-times

you need to use `navigation.push()` to run copies of your component with different params.